# how to see result in one row? --my id repetition in two different row--

Tags: mysql, sql

```
(SELECT
     id, post_date
     FROM mln_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order')
UNION
(SELECT
     post_id, meta_value
     FROM mln_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_order_total')
ORDER BY id
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKB9u.png)

Answer (score 0):

wrap your query and then use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
id, 
post_date 
FROM 
mln_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
UNION 
SELECT 
post_id, 
meta_value 
FROM 
mln_postmeta 
WHERE 
meta_key = '_order_total'
) final
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: thanks but i got this error: Error in query (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Sorry, My bad
Please see the updated query

Comment: Error in query (1055): Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'final.post_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Just remove the order by clause.
What version are you using by the way?

Comment: i actually use sql command in browser, localhost, not in the app sql

Answer (score 0):

Here's the trick, will create an imaginary column for you to join the 2nd subquery.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.post_date, t2.post_id, t2.meta_value
(SELECT
     id, post_date, 1 as col
     FROM mln_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
     ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) t1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
    post_id, meta_value, 1 as col
    FROM mln_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_order_total'
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) t2 ON t2.col = t1.col
```